# The "half" in "half-wittingly"

Tags: meaning, word-request

> The trailer ends on two characters **half-wittingly** playacting scrolling through their Onion-y looking social media feeds and allegorically muttering: “They say it’s bad for you, you know. The way we’re all connected.” / “Everything’s bad for you these days.” - https://www.pastemagazine.com/tv/dark-web/amazon-releases-trailer-for-darkweb/
>
> Just as U.S. and Soviet leaders Ronald Reagan and Mikhail Gorbachev agreed during the Cold War that “nuclear wars cannot be won and should never be fought,” Beijing and Washington should set some basic boundaries to their competition so that they do not **half-wittingly** destroy everything worth competing for. - https://www.armscontrol.org/act/2020-01/features/opportunities-nuclear-arms-control-engagement-china
>
> witting
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1 Done in full awareness or consciousness; deliberate.
>
> ‘the witting and unwitting complicity of the institutions’
>   1.1 (of a person) conscious or aware of the full facts of a situation.
>   ‘a witting accomplice’
>
> https://www.lexico.com/definition/witting

Why does "half-wittingly" seem to mean the same as "unwittingly"?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't mean "unwittingly". That means "unaware". Preceded by "half", it means "only partially aware" or "not fully aware", or "having a limited understanding."